# wso2 apeman3: Where do I put the APPID when configuring to call OpenWeather api?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm wrapping OpenweatherAPI in a wso2 api : WeatherAPI

The openweatherapi has an appid= passed in every call. Where do I put it in WeatherAPI wso2-config ?

Note that I'm **incorrectly** showing resource and **APPID** in the endpoint section.

The production endpoint must only read:

**https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/**

Please provide screenshot in your answer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Backend Endpoint: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/

There should be a resource named /weather which accepts query parameter q. (i.e the API query)

APPID is the token that should be sent in every call, which is an access key for Weather API.

Since the APPID is a constant and should be sent with every request, you can add it in a mediation sequence and engage it in the as the In-Sequence of the API.

You can use a sequence similar to this example.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="append_app_id">
    <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="fn:concat(get-property('axis2','REST_URL_POSTFIX'), '&amp;APPID=<value>')" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
</sequence>
```

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot?